# Why the column in my database table is not getting created?

Tags: android, sqlite

I have surfed through SO to the best possible extent. I hope there is no Syntax error in my table creation as mentioned in the answers to the similar questions as of mine.

Please help me resolve this.

The desired column is not getting created. This is the message am getting.

> E/SQLiteLog: (1) table ContactDetails has no column named
>   ContactNumber
>
> E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting ContactNumber=9655279648
>   ContactName=Ganesh R
>
> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table ContactDetails has no column named ContactNumber (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO ContactDetails(ContactNumber,ContactName) VALUES (?,?)

```
public class ProjectConstants {
            public static final String myDbName = "ContactsDatabase.db";
            public static final String myTableName = "ContactDetails";
            public static final String nameColumn = "ContactName";
            public static final String numberColumn = "ContactNumber";
        }
```

I have a separate class like above to store the values of constants that are accessed throughout the project.

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String SQLCreateEntries = "CREATE TABLE " + ProjectConstants.myTableName +
          " (" + ProjectConstants.nameColumn + ProjectConstants.numberColumn + " )";
    private static final String SQLDeleteEntries =
            "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + ProjectConstants.myTableName;

    public DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, String.valueOf(name), null, version);
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLCreateEntries);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLDeleteEntries);
        onCreate(sqLiteDatabase);
    }

    public void addContact(String nameLabel, String numberLabel) {
        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(ProjectConstants.nameColumn, nameLabel);
        contentValues.put(ProjectConstants.numberColumn, numberLabel);
        sqLiteDatabase.insert(ProjectConstants.myTableName, null, contentValues);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You created the table with

```
"CREATE TABLE " + ProjectConstants.myTableName +
      " (" + ProjectConstants.nameColumn + ProjectConstants.numberColumn + " )"
```

the syntax for `Create query` is

```
"CREATE TABLE MYTABLENAME (MYCOLUMNNAME MYCOLUMNTYPE, MYSECONDCOLUMNNAME MYSECONDCOLUMNTYPE,...)"
```

In your `Create query` you are missing both `types` and `commas`, fix it and the program will work :)

Comment: Added types, commas. Uninstalled the Application from Emulator. Reinstalled the apk. It worked fine. :)

Comment: glad it helped!